# Validate uniqueness of a field within a belongs_to, has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two rails Active Record models groups and accounts

```
group

    has_many :accounts

    id 
    name
    .. other infromation
    timestamps


Account

    belongs_to :group

    id
    name
    .. other information
    timestamps
```

I need to do a validates :name, :uniqueness => true in the accounts section but only under a group. As in i want the account name to be unique under a group. I know i can enforce a database unique constraint but can i do this using AR ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: true, scope: :group_id
```

For more information on the options available to validate, check out the [ActiveRecord Validations documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Thanks ! can only accept this in 11 mins ! thats what Stack overflow says :)

Comment: Is it `validate` or `validates`?

Comment: At least on Rails5, the correct way shoud be: `validates :name, :uniqueness { :scope => :group_id }`

Comment: It is validates indeed

Comment: I don't know if this answer was ever right, but the actual right way to do this in 2021 is: `validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :group_id }`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the accepted answer ever worked but as of today (22.02.2022 and rails 5/6/7) it does not work. As many already suggested in the comments the correct way would be:

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :group_id }
```